# Web API 2 404 Error when using jQuery Ajax

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-web-api-routing, asp.net-web-api2

I have a Web API 2 that I am consuming using jQuery Ajax and looking through the documentation you can now include a route inside the Controller itself so you could include additional parameters inside the GET request for example.

I have tried adding this for example:

```
   [Route("api/formHTML/{id}/{code}/{value}")]
        public IEnumerable<string> Get(int id, int code, int value)
        {
            return new string[] {"<html><head></head><body>Test</body></html>"};
        }
```

Which will basically return some HTML code.

I keep getting 404 not found when using a GET on api/formHTML/1/5/2

I still have this in my Global.asax which contains the default route mapping.

```
protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "DefaultApi",
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}"
        );
    }
```

Does anyone know why I would be getting a 404?

I know I could get the values by sending them as data object in the Get Request and using formBody in the Web API but I ideally wanted to use the above convention.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I have resolved this by reading the documentation again, I moved the default mapping to WebApiConfig.cs and then called this method from the Global.asax:

```
  GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
```

WebApiConfig.cs contains:

```
  public class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
              name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = System.Web.Http.RouteParameter.Optional }
           );
        }
    }
```

My issue was resolved!